# Problem with DateRangePicker backgroundColor since upgrading (Material3)

Tags: flutter

so since upgrading my flutter with the recent Material3 update I'm having trouble with the main background colour of DateRangePicker. The culprit seems to be backgroundColor

[image]

So I've tried doing what it's telling me but still can't seem to get the background to change. This is what I've tried....

[image]